# Django - how to automatically associate user while filling the form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

So I'm trying to create blog app. In this I have created a model Post which holds user submissions. I have also created a form to get user input into Post. The problem I'm facing is that I'm not able to automatically associate logged in user's id referenced while getting the input.

model.py :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse

class Post( models.Model):

    title = models.CharField( max_length = 225 )
    title_tag = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    author = models.ForeignKey( User , on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    body = models.TextField()
```

to temporarily resolve this I have found an option which gets users to select from a list of usernames

form.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post

class PostForm ( forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta :
        model = Post
        fields = {'title','title_tag', 'author','body'}

        widgets = {
            'title' : forms.TextInput( attrs= {'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder':'please write yur title'}),
            'title_tag' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'author': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

view.py :

```
class CreatePost ( CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name= 'create_post.html'
    #fields  = '__all__'

def create_post(request) :

    form = Post (request.POST or None)
    context = {
        'form_': form
    }

    if request.method == 'POST':

        if form.is_valid():
            publish = form.save(commit=False)
            #publish.author = request.user
            publish.save()

    return render(request, 'create_p.html', context )
```

I used class CreatePost to render this view. It works but the problem is I have to choose which user to associate Post object manually. I tried to bypass this using function create_post but rendering it gives me "RelatedObjectDoesNotExist Post has no author" error.

Can you please guide me  this problem Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user must be logged in first. Then you can override the [`form_valid`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user) method like this.

```
class CreatePost(LoginRequireMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name= 'create_post.html'
    #fields  = '__all__'

    def form_valid(self, form):
       form.instance.author = self.request.user
       return super(CreatePost, self).form_valid(form)
```

Also you need to remove the field `author` as a required field from your form since you are handling this field by yourself in the view.

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta :
        model = Post
        fields = ['title','title_tag','body']
```

Comment: many thanks for your answer. It really works great but it kind of messes up the ordring of fields which appear in my form. I'm using the snippet {{ form.as_p }} and post methord. Can you suggest a way to properly order the form ? In the form I'm getting input of body above the input of title.

Answer (score 0):

first of all the user must be associated with the models so try

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
```

class Post( models.Model):

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="user",null=True)
title = models.CharField( max_length = 225 )
title_tag = models.CharField(max_length=225)
author = models.ForeignKey( User , on_delete=models.CASCADE )
body = models.TextField()
```